# aplay sound file keeps playing non stop

Tags: c++, opencv, audio

Ive a code which plays wav sound whenever a face is detected. Im a bit noob so please help.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/** Global variables */
String faceCascadePath;
CascadeClassifier faceCascade;

void detectFaceOpenCVHaar(CascadeClassifier faceCascade, Mat &frameOpenCVHaar, int inHeight=300, int inWidth=0)
{
    int frameHeight = frameOpenCVHaar.rows;
    int frameWidth = frameOpenCVHaar.cols;
    if (!inWidth)
        inWidth = (int)((frameWidth / (float)frameHeight) * inHeight);

    float scaleHeight = frameHeight / (float)inHeight;
    float scaleWidth = frameWidth / (float)inWidth;

    Mat frameOpenCVHaarSmall, frameGray;
    resize(frameOpenCVHaar, frameOpenCVHaarSmall, Size(inWidth, inHeight));
    cvtColor(frameOpenCVHaarSmall, frameGray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(frameGray, faces);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
      int x1 = (int)(faces[i].x * scaleWidth);
      int y1 = (int)(faces[i].y * scaleHeight);
      int x2 = (int)((faces[i].x + faces[i].width) * scaleWidth);
      int y2 = (int)((faces[i].y + faces[i].height) * scaleHeight);
      rectangle(frameOpenCVHaar, Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2), Scalar(0,255,0), (int)(frameHeight/150.0), 4);
     
      string str1 = "aplay ";
      str1 = str1 + " out.wav" + " & ";
      const char *command = str1.c_str();
      system(command);

    }
}


int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    faceCascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
    if(!faceCascade.load(faceCascadePath))
    {
        printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n");
        return -1;
    }

    VideoCapture source(1);
    //if (argc == 1)
    //    source.open(0, CAP_V4L);
    //else
    //    source.open(argv[1]);  
    Mat frame;

    double tt_opencvHaar = 0;
    double fpsOpencvHaar = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        source >> frame;
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        double t = cv::getTickCount();
        detectFaceOpenCVHaar(faceCascade, frame);
        tt_opencvHaar = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t)/cv::getTickFrequency();
        fpsOpencvHaar = 1/tt_opencvHaar;
         
        putText(frame, format("OpenCV HAAR ; FPS = %.2f",fpsOpencvHaar), Point(10, 50), FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.3, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);

        imshow("OpenCV - HAAR Face Detection", frame);

        int k = waitKey(5);
        if(k == 27)
        {
            destroyAllWindows();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

TO COMPILE

└──╼ $g++  face_detection_.cpp  -o face_det `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

└──╼ $./face_det

The only problem with this code is logical issue. Whenever Im in front of the camera it keeps playing the wav file and the sound is same if you are joining a video conference from two devices simultaneously (i.e. echo)

I want to play the sound only once if lets say a face is continously detected for 5 seconds. So if a face is detected for 24 seconds, the sound should play only 4 times (every 5th second).

How to do it ?

Comment: Can anyone please help me ??

Comment: So it seems you are able to detect the faces ( I suggest you to use other face detection model instead haar ). All you need to make a timer to check how long face exist on the screen, and play the sound accordingly