# Unable to play wav file in linux using alsa

Tags: c++, audio, alsa

So Im trying to play a wave file on raspberry pi in C++ with this code

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define PCM_DEVICE "default"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned int pcm, tmp, dir;
    int rate, channels, seconds;
    snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t *params;
    snd_pcm_uframes_t frames;
    char *buff;
    int buff_size, loops;

    if (argc < 4) {
        printf("Usage: %s <sample_rate> <channels> <seconds>\n",
                                argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    rate     = atoi(argv[1]);
    channels = atoi(argv[2]);
    seconds  = atoi(argv[3]);

    /* Open the PCM device in playback mode */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, PCM_DEVICE,
                    SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't open \"%s\" PCM device. %s\n",
                    PCM_DEVICE, snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Allocate parameters object and fill it with default values*/
    snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&params);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_any(pcm_handle, params);

    /* Set parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access(pcm_handle, params,
                    SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set interleaved mode. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format(pcm_handle, params,
                        SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set format. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels(pcm_handle, params, channels) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set channels number. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near(pcm_handle, params, &rate, 0) < 0) 
        printf("ERROR: Can't set rate. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Write parameters */
    if (pcm = snd_pcm_hw_params(pcm_handle, params) < 0)
        printf("ERROR: Can't set harware parameters. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));

    /* Resume information */
    printf("PCM name: '%s'\n", snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle));

    printf("PCM state: %s\n", snd_pcm_state_name(snd_pcm_state(pcm_handle)));

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels(params, &tmp);
    printf("channels: %i ", tmp);

    if (tmp == 1)
        printf("(mono)\n");
    else if (tmp == 2)
        printf("(stereo)\n");

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate(params, &tmp, 0);
    printf("rate: %d bps\n", tmp);

    printf("seconds: %d\n", seconds);   

    /* Allocate buffer to hold single period */
    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(params, &frames, 0);

    buff_size = frames * channels * 2 /* 2 -> sample size */;
    buff = (char *) malloc(buff_size);

    snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_time(params, &tmp, NULL);

    for (loops = (seconds * 1000000) / tmp; loops > 0; loops--) {

        if (pcm = read(0, buff, buff_size) == 0) {
            printf("Early end of file.\n");
            return 0;
        }

        if (pcm = snd_pcm_writei(pcm_handle, buff, frames) == -EPIPE) {
            printf("XRUN.\n");
            snd_pcm_prepare(pcm_handle);
        } else if (pcm < 0) {
            printf("ERROR. Can't write to PCM device. %s\n", snd_strerror(pcm));
        }

    }

    snd_pcm_drain(pcm_handle);
    snd_pcm_close(pcm_handle);
    free(buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation : gcc -o play test2.cpp -lasound

pi@raspberrypi:~/tinyalsa $ ./play 44100 2 2 < hello.wav

```
PCM name: 'default'
PCM state: PREPARED
channels: 2 (stereo)
rate: 44100 bps
seconds: 2
Early end of file.
```

While playing a wave file Im getting just a click sound on speaker for very very short time and then "Early end of file" (as can be seen above).

But if I run this :-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/tinyalsa $ ./play 44100 2 2 < /dev/urandom 
PCM name: 'default'
PCM state: PREPARED
channels: 2 (stereo)
rate: 44100 bps
seconds: 2
```

, then it plays a staic noise for 2 seconds. But why is it not playing the wav file, I cant understand.

Can anyone help me fix this issue ?

Comment: read(0, ... bah blah indicates that the file should be in standard input of your program? Apparently there are nothing so it returns 0 bytes read.

Comment: @ÖöTiib sorry but I didnt get you.  If I run "./play 44100 2 2 < /dev/urandom", then it plays a staic noise for 2 seconds. But why is it not playing the wav file.

Comment: I do not know. Why don't you printf your pcm out to see how lot of bytes it manages to read from that wav? Maybe stdin is by default in some odd mode and you need to reopen it in binary mode like std::freopen(nullptr, "rb", stdin);

Comment: `snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;`      `snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle,`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин can you also help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916568/aplay-sound-file-keeps-playing-non-stop